# Unknown PG numeric type 25

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am working on a project with Python-Flask, SQL Alchemy, & Postgres qith psycopg2 package.
The project's save the data in database successfully, but throws error "Unknown PG numeric type 25" while refreshing object.

```
        project.second_payment_percent = int(request.form.get("second_payment_percent", 0)) if request.form.get("second_payment_percent", 0) else 0
        project.second_payment_before = int(request.form.get("second_payment_before", 120))
        project.currency_id = int(request.form.get("currency_code"))
        project.security_deposit = int(request.form.get("security_deposit", 0))
        project.apa = int(request.form.get("apa", 0))
        project.vat_schema_id = request.form.get("vat_schema") if request.form.get("vat_schema", 0) else None

        if project.apa > 0:
            project.security_deposit = int(project.project_price) * int(project.apa) / 100

        db.session.add(project)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.refresh(project)
        db.session.flush()
```

The error I get is

```
File "<project directory>utils/app_views.py", line 56, in decorated
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "<project directory>views/admin/project.py", line 347, in admin_products_save_accommodation
db.session.refresh(project)
File "<project directory>models/project.py", line 297, in serialize
reviews, avg_rating = self.reviews
File "<project directory>models/project.py", line 269, in reviews
robj = db.session.query(ProjectReviews).filter_by(product_id=self.id).order_by('time_created').all()
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 237, in __get__
return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 578, in get
value = state._load_expired(state, passive)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 474, in _load_expired
self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 664, in load_scalar_attributes
only_load_props=attribute_names)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 219, in load_on_ident
return q.one()
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2693, in one
ret = list(self)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2736, in __iter__
return self._execute_and_instances(context)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2751, in _execute_and_instances
result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql, distilled_params
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1161, in _execute_context
result = context.get_result_proxy()
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 474, in get_result_proxy
return _result.ResultProxy(self)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 495, in __init__
self._init_metadata()
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 524, in _init_metadata
self._metadata = ResultMetaData(self, metadata)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 221, in __init__
in enumerate(result_columns)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 764, in get_result_processor
return type_._cached_result_processor(self.dialect, coltype)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 392, in _cached_result_processor
d[coltype] = rp = d['impl'].result_processor(dialect, coltype)
File "<venv path>lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 361, in result_processor
"Unknown PG numeric type: %d" % coltype)
InvalidRequestError: Unknown PG numeric type: 25
```

I have tried many things, but failed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] based on `robj = db.session.query(ProjectReviews).filter_by(product_id=self.id).order_by('time_created').all()`. The trigger might be just the `self.id`, causing an automatic refresh, so please provide the models.

Comment: It was, Data type `float` in SQLAlchemy being created as `VARCHAR` in postgres.

Answer (score 10):

I guess one of the fields in your table is a text and you are trying to retrieve it as a number.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_type where oid = 25;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+---------
typname        | text
```

Comment: It was, Data type `float` in SQLAlchemy being created as `VARCHAR` in postgres.